# How should I solve this phaser?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, visual-studio, phaser-framework

[image]
[image]

I started Phaser, and if you look at the Visual Studio Guide on the Phaser website, you keep getting errors. Did anyone solve this problem?

Comment: You are following an old Phaser 2 tutorial, but you installed Phaser 3.

Comment: You should share the codes and errors as text so that they can be read and edited by users. You should read this article: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned in the comments, I also assume that you are mixing to phaser versions.

I would use **Phaser 3** *(here is a older post *"comparing"* the versions [Should I use Phaser 3 or Phaser 2/CE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52763504/should-i-use-phaser-3-or-phaser-2-ce) )*

**Just to be on the save side:**

- Get the right Version of phaser you want to use:

  - For Phaser 3: https://phaser.io/download/stable
  - For Phaser 2 CE: https://phaser.io/download/release/2.19.1

**Select the tutorials/examples for the version you want to use:**

- Phaser 3: https://phaser.io/examples
- Phaser 2 CE: https://phaser.io/examples/v2

**For example, for your `sprite` problem:**

- Phaser 3 Example how to add a sprite:
  https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/animation/60fps-animation-test

  ```
  ...
  create(){  
      ...
      this.add.sprite(400, 484, 'walker', 'frame_0000');
    sprite.play('walk'); 
      ...
  }
  ...
  ```
- Phaser 2 CE Example how to add a sprite:
  https://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/add-a-sprite

  ```
  ...
  var test = game.add.sprite(200, 200, 'mushroom');
  ...
  ```

I hope this helps, with your problem